# What is the best way to check "method call" match format using checkstyle?

Tags: java, regex, annotations, spell-checking, checkstyle

I have a group of methods that belong a single class that should contain at-least 2 parameters. The first one should be of type "literal" string (e.g. instance.do("literal_string", obj) - should be specified just right in the method call line itself). As next first parameter should also match a given regex pattern. The second argument can have any value (Object).

Additionally first parameter should be unique across whole project (this part is not really that important to consider).

Are there any possibilities to implement a check for conditions I've listed above? (Perhaps with checkstyle? Or custom Java annotations?)

**Upd. Such a check should be preferably executed during dev-time (e.g. hinting a yellow light bulb in eclipse).**

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
if(nameOfStringVar.matches("regex")){
    throw new java.lang.Error("First arg did not match the regex");
}
Objects.requireNonNull(nameOfSecondVariable);
```

?

Comment: No not really this will work in runtime, the target to perform such a check in dev-time. (I've updated the question to prevent confusion)

Comment: sorry but I don't think that's possible! But I could be wrong! good Luck!